# Can an offline application pass review?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

Our app makes use of a refresh token if available (offline).  Does offline access force a consent page (for each domain user?), and how can an offline application pass review if the requirement is no extra consent pages?

Answer (score 0):

Requesting offline access with a refresh token will always prompt the user. Instead, create a service account in the Google Developers Console project you are using, and use the service account to impersonate users in the domain.